Macbook doesn't sleep and keeps restarting itself with error
I have this macbook pro 13 with M1 and it currently runs sonoma 14.5, since before updating I have been experiencing restart issues while it was asleep, I will open the laptop and it shows laptop has been restarted with the error below.
The touchbar stopped working one day and still doesn't work. After updating to sonoma 14.5 the laptop stopped going to sleep when I closed it, sometimes the screen stays on and sometimes it doesn't. I've made a fresh install but nothing has changed. Any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks.
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffe001410782c): "virtual IOReturn ADPParamFIFO::programFIFO(IOMemoryMap *): ADP FIFO still busy after 1000ms" @ADPParamFIFO.cpp:264
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 23F79
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 23.5.0: Wed May  1 20:16:51 PDT 2024; root:xnu-10063.121.3~5/RELEASE_ARM64_T8103
Fileset Kernelcache UUID: 43472D74A84C3E06D501C28D43B2A59A
Kernel UUID: AC23A9AC-3C84-3F66-B149-7EBD8B3CBC67
Boot session UUID: 886ACF62-81F5-4768-A0EC-66E10F4DDD12
iBoot version: iBoot-10151.121.1
secure boot?: YES
roots installed: 0
Paniclog version: 14
KernelCache slide: 0x000000000a624000
KernelCache base:  0xfffffe0011628000
Kernel slide:      0x000000000a62c000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffe0011630000
Kernel text exec slide: 0x000000000bb40000
Kernel text exec base:  0xfffffe0012b44000
mach_absolute_time: 0x101d1ed6b5
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x66a6ddc8 0x000c197c
  Sleep   : 0x66a711b9 0x00088725
  Wake    : 0x66a7153b 0x00098050
  Calendar: 0x66a7161b 0x0009db35

Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xfffffe1014e58000 - 0xfffffe3014e58000
  . VM    : 0xfffffe1014e58000 - 0xfffffe14e1b24000
  . RO    : 0xfffffe14e1b24000 - 0xfffffe167b4bc000
  . GEN0  : 0xfffffe167b4bc000 - 0xfffffe1b48188000
  . GEN1  : 0xfffffe1b48188000 - 0xfffffe2014e54000
  . GEN2  : 0xfffffe2014e54000 - 0xfffffe24e1b20000
  . GEN3  : 0xfffffe24e1b20000 - 0xfffffe29ae7ec000
  . DATA  : 0xfffffe29ae7ec000 - 0xfffffe3014e58000
  Metadata: 0xfffffe54270e4000 - 0xfffffe542f0e4000
  Bitmaps : 0xfffffe542f0e4000 - 0xfffffe54306e0000
  Extra   : 0 - 0

CORE 0 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0012cf2cb8
CORE 1 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0012cf4448
CORE 2 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0012cf4448
CORE 3 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0012cf4440
CORE 4 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0012cf4448
CORE 5 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0012cf4448
CORE 6 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0012cf4448
CORE 7 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0012cf4448
TPIDRx_ELy = {1: 0xfffffe2015ca8000  0: 0x0000000000000000  0ro: 0x0000000000000000 }
CORE 0 PVH locks held: None
CORE 1 PVH locks held: None
CORE 2 PVH locks held: None
CORE 3 PVH locks held: None
CORE 4 PVH locks held: None
CORE 5 PVH locks held: None
CORE 6 PVH locks held: None
CORE 7 PVH locks held: None
CORE 0 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
CORE 1: PC=0xfffffe0012cef1c0, LR=0xfffffe0012cef1bc, FP=0xfffffe5338217e80
CORE 2: PC=0xfffffe0012cef1c0, LR=0xfffffe0012cef1bc, FP=0xfffffe53383c7e80
CORE 3: PC=0xfffffe0012cef1c0, LR=0xfffffe0012cef1bc, FP=0xfffffe5338657e80
CORE 4: PC=0xfffffe0012bd9600, LR=0xfffffe0012bd9600, FP=0xfffffe53383a3ef0
CORE 5: PC=0xfffffe0012bd9600, LR=0xfffffe0012bd9600, FP=0xfffffe533859fef0
CORE 6: PC=0xfffffe0012bd9600, LR=0xfffffe0012bd9600, FP=0xfffffe533854bef0
CORE 7: PC=0xfffffe0012bd9600, LR=0xfffffe0012bd9600, FP=0xfffffe53387efef0
Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space
Panicked task 0xfffffe2014f8a678: 0 pages, 491 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xfffffe2015ca8000, backtrace: 0xfffffe53387b33e0, tid: 52348
          lr: 0xfffffe0012b9e048  fp: 0xfffffe53387b3470
          lr: 0xfffffe0012ceb4d8  fp: 0xfffffe53387b34e0
          lr: 0xfffffe0012ce9708  fp: 0xfffffe53387b35a0
          lr: 0xfffffe0012b4bba8  fp: 0xfffffe53387b35b0
          lr: 0xfffffe0012b9d928  fp: 0xfffffe53387b3960
          lr: 0xfffffe00133bd6d0  fp: 0xfffffe53387b3980
          lr: 0xfffffe001410782c  fp: 0xfffffe53387b39b0
          lr: 0xfffffe00140f3c24  fp: 0xfffffe53387b39f0
          lr: 0xfffffe00140bf404  fp: 0xfffffe53387b3a20
          lr: 0xfffffe00140c38a8  fp: 0xfffffe53387b3a80
          lr: 0xfffffe00140d43e8  fp: 0xfffffe53387b3b20
          lr: 0xfffffe00152660b8  fp: 0xfffffe53387b3b60
          lr: 0xfffffe001525829c  fp: 0xfffffe53387b3bb0
          lr: 0xfffffe00132bc898  fp: 0xfffffe53387b3c20
          lr: 0xfffffe0015266340  fp: 0xfffffe53387b3cb0
          lr: 0xfffffe001329010c  fp: 0xfffffe53387b3d90
          lr: 0xfffffe001328faf0  fp: 0xfffffe53387b3df0
          lr: 0xfffffe0012bffa64  fp: 0xfffffe53387b3e30
          lr: 0xfffffe0012c00ac4  fp: 0xfffffe53387b3f20
          lr: 0xfffffe0012b54f08  fp: 0x0000000000000000
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily(343.0)[AF502C07-259C-31D5-AA1C-9FE809898E15]@0xfffffe0015231ac0->0xfffffe0015274213
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[111F012A-F12D-349B-A25C-6EC373681EBF]@0xfffffe001354c8e0->0xfffffe00135a08ff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver(265.0.0)[F5A94589-C093-3A1E-8EE3-9337B8AF8138]@0xfffffe0013f8c450->0xfffffe001401df53
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[01C95951-C0A2-3F11-BEB9-7290CA8EFE4F]@0xfffffe00141079d0->0xfffffe0014138943
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAVFamily(1.0.0)[DC469449-16EE-33D6-A8A6-95040609B9DF]@0xfffffe0014d5ac90->0xfffffe0014de4aff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(352.50.1)[405AD4ED-22CC-339C-A58F-2F81660DE066]@0xfffffe0015441140->0xfffffe001546e84f
         com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH13G-DFR(140.0)[4A77A778-45AF-3278-B8B8-766380B9D19E]@0xfffffe00140b7ba0->0xfffffe00141079cf
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[111F012A-F12D-349B-A25C-6EC373681EBF]@0xfffffe001354c8e0->0xfffffe00135a08ff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver(265.0.0)[F5A94589-C093-3A1E-8EE3-9337B8AF8138]@0xfffffe0013f8c450->0xfffffe001401df53
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAVFamily(1.0.0)[DC469449-16EE-33D6-A8A6-95040609B9DF]@0xfffffe0014d5ac90->0xfffffe0014de4aff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily(343.0.0)[AF502C07-259C-31D5-AA1C-9FE809898E15]@0xfffffe0015231ac0->0xfffffe0015274213
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(352.50.1)[405AD4ED-22CC-339C-A58F-2F81660DE066]@0xfffffe0015441140->0xfffffe001546e84f

last started kext at 341764504: com.paragon-software.filesystems.ntfs   187.1.16 (addr 0xfffffe0011510000, size 14138)
loaded kexts:
com.paragon-software.filesystems.ntfs   187.1.16
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 7440.8
com.apple.driver.CoreKDL    1
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricServices 1
com.apple.driver.AppleALSColorSensor    1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPVoiceTrigger   340.42
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.ReadWriteDiskImage  493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.UDIFDiskImage   493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.RAMBackingStore 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.FileBackingStore    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
com.apple.driver.SEPHibernation 1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 4.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDeviceNCM  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.9
com.apple.filesystems.tmpfs 1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMP   1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMPFirmware   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.nfs   1
com.apple.filesystems.lifs  1
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  2236.120.10
com.apple.IOTextEncryptionFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  650.120.1
com.apple.security.BootPolicy   1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartIO2  1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleCS42L83Audio  740.41
com.apple.driver.AppleDPDisplayTCON 1
com.apple.AppleEmbeddedSimpleSPINORFlasher  1
com.apple.driver.AppleTAS5770LAmp   740.41
com.apple.driver.AppleSummitLCD 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020SOCTuner 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103CLPCv3   1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PMGR 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XNCO   1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000DWI  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleEventLogHandler   1
com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptController   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleAVE2  760.30.1
com.apple.driver.AppleJPEGDriver    6.6.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAVD   742
com.apple.driver.AppleSerialShim    1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH13G-DCP    140.0
com.apple.AGXG13G   282.14
com.apple.driver.AudioDMAController-T8103   350.2
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000AES  1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleSynopsysUSB40XHCI 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothModule   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSamsungSerial 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe   1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020DART 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSynopsysMIPIDSI   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8920XPWM   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8940XI2C   1.0.0d2
com.apple.driver.AppleSPIMC 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8101 1
com.apple.driver.AppleM68Buttons    1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUserHCI    1
com.apple.iokit.IOKitRegistryCompatibility  1
com.apple.iokit.EndpointSecurity    1
com.apple.driver.AppleUIO   1
com.apple.driver.AppleDiskImages2   276.120.5
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 2.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   405
com.apple.kec.InvalidateHmac    1
com.apple.kec.AppleEncryptedArchive 1
com.apple.driver.driverkit.serial   6.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 1220.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 7440.8
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   9.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   7440.3
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    7440.9
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  7440.9
com.apple.driver.AppleMesaSEPDriver 100.99
com.apple.iokit.IOBiometricFamily   1
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPAudio  340.4
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.KernelBacked    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPHDCPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleTrustedAccessory  1
com.apple.iokit.AppleSEPGenericTransfer 1
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltUSBDownAdapter 1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    8.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    8.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBTM   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl  1
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedPCI  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebug    1
com.apple.nke.ppp   1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleDCPDPTXProxy  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.DCPDPFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBSDKextStarter    3
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.IOHIDPowerSource   1
com.apple.driver.AppleCallbackPowerSource   1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleSyntheticGameController   11.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCSEmbeddedAudio   740.41
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransportSPI   7440.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  7440.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSPU   1
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    7440.1
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextG13GRTBuddy    282.14
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextRTBuddy64  282.14
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudio 740.41
com.apple.iokit.AppleARMIISAudio    340.16
com.apple.driver.IISAudioIsolatedStreamECProxy  340.16
com.apple.driver.ExclavesAudioKext  1
com.apple.driver.AppleDiagnosticDataAccessReadOnly  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleNANDConfigAccess  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleStockholmControl  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMIPMU   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleDialogPMU 1.0.1
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   1250.2
com.apple.driver.ApplePassthroughPPM    3.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePMGR  1
com.apple.driver.AppleARMWatchdogTimer  1
com.apple.driver.AppleH13CameraInterface    8.502.0
com.apple.driver.AppleH11ANEInterface   7.453.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSART  1
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily-DCP  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDCP   1
com.apple.driver.DCPAVFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareKit   1
com.apple.driver.AppleA7IOP-ASCWrap-v4  1.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOGPUFamily 93.40.3
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103TypeCPhy 1
com.apple.driver.AppleA7IOP-M3Wrap-v2   1.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleDisplayCrossbar   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IODisplayPortFamily 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCIARM    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCI   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBDeviceFamily   2.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleSynopsysUSBXHCI   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleTypeCPhy  1
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedUSBHost   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMI  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileApNonce 1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    7.2.81
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIeC    1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 9.3.3
com.apple.iokit.IOPortFamily    1.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePIODMA    1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIe 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebugService 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.13.0
com.apple.driver.IOImageLoader  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOLYHAL    1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH13G-DFR    140.0
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver 265.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCA2-T8103    840.3
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudioLibs 340.8
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareUpdateKext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleGPIOICController  1.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFireStormErrorHandler 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultiFunctionManager  1
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedPCIE  1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    1250.2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    598
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   9.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPKeyStore   2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    556
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  245
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.RTBuddy    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedTempSensor    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPMU    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAccessoryManager  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   495
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   495
com.apple.driver.AppleRSMChannel    1
com.apple.iokit.IORSMFamily 1
com.apple.driver.AppleLockdownMode  1
com.apple.driver.AppleIPAppender    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1.0
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IODARTFamily   1
com.apple.driver.AppleA7IOP 1.0.2
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricSensor   2
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.AUC   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   352.50.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAVFamily  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDCPFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCECFamily 1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudio2Family  1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIISController 340.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAudioClockLibs    340.8
com.apple.driver.FairPlayIOKit  71.10.0
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform   1.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.security.quarantine   4
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.CoreAnalyticsFamily 1
com.apple.security.AppleImage4  6.3.0
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.iokit.IOCryptoAcceleratorFamily   1.0.1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.Compression   1.0
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    14.0


** Stackshot Succeeded ** Bytes Traced 298016 (Uncompressed 732224) **



You've got Paragon's NTFS kernel extension installed. I would recommend testing without it.
Have a look to see what else you've installed, which may no longer be compatible with a newer OS version.
If you've ruled out software, and there's still a problem, then take it to an Apple Store, or other authorised Apple repair shop, for assessment of the hardware.

I did try it with a fresh install and it was still  the case, I even went back to monterey but it would never go to sleep. the restarting stopped after updating to sequoia beta but it still wouldn't sleep.

When you say "fresh install", do you mean a "clean" OS, without restoring your old software and settings? If so, I'd get the hardware checked.

yes sir, a clean OS. I was afraid it would come to that, I guess there's no other way.
